# Javascript SetTimeout chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, chaining

This may be a simple problem but I can't seem to embed a variable parameter in a function for future execution. "alert" is the function I'd like to delay execution, with the parameter 0, 1, 2 etc

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var init = function init() {
      for (var i = 0, max = 3; i < max; i++) {
        var then;
        then = (function(jj) {
          return jj;
        }(i));
        var pp = function(jj) {
          return alert(then);
        };

        setTimeout(function() {
         pp();
        }, then * 1000);
      }

    };
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <button onclick="init();"></button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is complicated convoluted code and I'm quite sure that if we understood what you were really trying to do, there would be much less convoluted ways of doing it.

Comment: What is the problem with the code (besides the confusion)? The values in the alerts are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ask a question so I'll assume any implementation that produces the results you were expecting is what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function createfunc(i) {
        return function() { alert(i); };
    }

    var init = function init() {
        for (var i = 0, max = 3; i < max; i++) {
            var func = createfunc(i);
            setTimeout(func, i * 1000);
        }
    };

  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <button onclick="init();"></button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will alert a number, then wait a second and alert another number. Until 3 is reached:

```
var init = function() {
    var counter = 0, //Start
        max = 3 //End

    var count = function() {
        alert(counter) //Alert

        if ( counter < max ) { //If we havent reached 3 then queue this function to be called again
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                count()
            }, 1000)
        }

        counter++
    }

    count() //Start the counter
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EXwH2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You enclosed the first function in a closure but not the second, so you essentially set your `pp` var to the last iteration before `setTimeout` is called for the first time. What's your intent with the `then` variable? If you want to stagger the calls, each with their own value, you might want to put the call to `setTimeout` itself within its own closure:

```
 var init = function init() {
    for (var i = 0, max = 3; i < max; i++) {
        (function (jj) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert(jj);
            }, jj * 1000);
        })(i);
    }
};
```